# Estimating Joint Probability from limited data

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, joint-distribution, operations-research

This is probably a broad question but I am interested in getting the Joint PDF for n random variables each of which can take integer values within a finite range.
I have data in the form of time series for these n random variables (it should be possible to see a correlation from this).
For better understanding, see this below example:

| Time | $$X_1$$ | $$X_2$$ | $$X_3$$ | $$X_4$$ | $$X_5$$ | ... | $$X_n$$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 5 | 7 | 4 | 7 |
| 6 | 3 | 8 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 7 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 1 | 8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

This is what the data looks like. Now I want to estimate the joint PDF of these random variables so that I can use their realizations for some simulations.
What I know about these random variables is that they have a finite range.
The number of random variables is fixed, i.e. n is known.
How do I go about this?

Comment: Do you have an enormous amount of data?  If not, you must make specific assumptions to narrow the possible distribution -- in which case, your question "how do I go about this" requires several textbooks just to outline the possibilities.